# serialization objects in java

Tags: java, serialization, java-io

Is there a way to get around during the serialization of the object full match / repetition of the way? For example:

on the client -

> com.example.myProjectOne.model.MyClass

on the server side -

> com.example.notMyProject.entity.MyClass

I get -

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.example.myProjectOne.model.MyClass

with the full coincidence of the names of all work packages

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

private SettingsConnection settingsConnection;
private OnReceiveObject onReceiveObject;
private Serializer serializer;

/**
 * @param remoteServerAddress - address remote server
 * @param inputPort - the port on which the is server
 * @param outputPort - the port which used for send
 * @param password - the password which should to be same on the client side and the server side
 * @param handler - defines the name of the method, which should to be called, after received the data on server side
 */
public Server(String remoteServerAddress, int inputPort, int outputPort, String password, OnReceiveObject handler) {
    settingsConnection = new SettingsConnection();
    settingsConnection.setAddressRemoteServer(remoteServerAddress);
    settingsConnection.setInputPort(inputPort);
    settingsConnection.setOutputPort(outputPort);
    this.onReceiveObject = handler;
    serializer = new Serializer();
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public void sendData(Serializable object, String callBackFunction) {

    Container container = new Container();

    try {
        container.setData(serializer.serialize(object), container.getInitVector()));
        container.setHandler(callBackFunction);
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(settingsConnection.getAddressRemoteServer());

        try (Socket socketConnectionToSever = new Socket(ipAddress, settingsConnection.getOutputPort())) {
            OutputStream outputStream = socketConnectionToSever.getOutputStream();
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.write(serializer.serialize(container));
                outputStream.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    final ExecutorService asyncTakesCode = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    Runnable threadTaskServer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(settingsConnection.getInputPort());
                while (true) {
                    Socket connectionSocketClient = serverSocket.accept();
                    asyncTakesCode.submit(new ThreadTaskClient(connectionSocketClient));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Thread threadServer = new Thread(threadTaskServer);
    threadServer.start();
}

private class ThreadTaskClient implements Runnable {
    private final Socket connectionSocketClient;

    private ThreadTaskClient(Socket connectionSocketClient) {
        this.connectionSocketClient = connectionSocketClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = connectionSocketClient.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Object o = serializer.deserialize(IOUtils.readFully(inputStream, -1, false));
            if (o instanceof Container) {
                Container container = (Container) o;
                Serializable remoteObject = (Serializable) serializer.deserialize(container.getData()));
                String callBackFunction = container.getHandler();
                onReceiveObject.processRemoteObject(remoteObject, callBackFunction);
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                connectionSocketClient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: show up your code.

Comment: Do you have any control over *how* it's serialized?

Comment: Don´t forget to use the annotations @Entity etc.

Comment: @Bohemian in general, yes, of course

Comment: Then use JSON with Jackson or Gson or whatever.

Comment: The way to 'get round it' is not to cause the problem in the first place. Use the same classes at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using java's serialization, the classes must match both ends.

Include your class in the server side's classpath.

If you can't do that, you could make it work by effectively creating an alias of your class name for the other class:

```
package com.example.myProjectOne.model;

public class MyClass extends com.example.notMyProject.entity.MyClass {
}
```

There are a few caveats of course, for example the would only work if the two classes share the same non-transient instance field names and types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You have to extend the default `ObjectInputStream` and override the `resolveClass` method (maybe others, not sure).

So, for example:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( lis ) {
        protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass osc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            if (osc.getName().contains("some.package.element")) {
                try {
                    Field nameField = osc.getClass().getField("name");
                    nameField.setAccessible(true);
                    nameField.set(osc, osc.getName().replace("some.package.element", "another.package.element"));
                    nameField.setAccessible(false); // hack because "name" is private
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // ...
                }
            }
            return super.resolveClass(osc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @WilkinOh  thank you very much, now try, if you do not mind, I could ask you a couple of questions, if I do not get something)

Comment: Sure, feel free, but be aware that this approach might require lots of hacking :)